# Why is ncurses not displaying text?

Tags: php, ncurses

```
ncurses_init();

ncurses_addstr(0, 0, "test");
ncurses_refresh();
ncurses_getch();
ncurses_end();
```

This should be displaying "test" at the top left, but it isn't. Any idea why?

PHP 5.1.6
CentOS 5.5

Got ncurses through yum install ncurses

it recognizes the ncurses functions, so I assume it *should* be working

Comment: @Phil Lello, edited to answer your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UH OH! Looks like *someone* forgot to read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-addstr.php)!

```
ncurses_mvaddstr(0, 0, "test");
```

Comment: Hm. Previously I didn't need to do that. I wonder why. But sure enough, that works.

Comment: Beat me while I was waiting on PECL :(

Comment: With you there... I just wish there were RPM/DEB wrappers for these things... installing dependancies for PECL/PEAR wastes so much time (and clutters servers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change [ncurses_addstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-addstr.php) to [ncurses_mvaddstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-mvaddstr.php)

Comment: What do you mean, "why"? One function does what you want, and the other doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't the pointer start at 0,0? why would i need to move it to 0,0?

Comment: If you don't want to set the position, use ncurses_addstr without a position.